# Agregar ExpandableListView en un Navigation Drawer Android JAVA

Tags: java, android, android-studio, navigationview

Debido a que en mi Navigation Drawer cada vez tengo más opciones he tenido que buscar una forma de hacer que algunos items sean desplegables. Es decir, al tocar alguno estos, de desplieguen o aparezcan los items correspondientes al grupo seleccionado.
He buscado bastante y la forma más utilizada es con un ExpandableListView, me está costando migrar el menú anterior a este nuevo menú desplegable.

La forma en que tengo mi Navigation Drawer es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Resource tipo menú:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/general"
    android:title="Menú">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/inicio"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_home_24"
            android:title="Inicio" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/altaExcepciones"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_language_24"
            android:title="Alta Excepciones" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/borrarHuella"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_delete_forever_24"
            android:title="Borrar Huella" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/descaducarUsuario"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_how_to_reg_24"
            android:title="Descaducar clave de usuario" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/olvidoClave"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_help_outline_24"
            android:title="Olvido de Clave" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/kardexSocio"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_text_snippet_24"
            android:title="Kardex del Socio" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/reversionBoveda"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_undo_24"
            android:title="Reversion de corte de caja boveda" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/altaBloqueoCAH"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_block_24"
            android:title="Alta Bloqueo cah" />
    </menu>
</item>

</menu>
```

**Activity_Inicio:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/frmInicio"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".vistas.Inicio">

<include
    layout="@layout/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<include
    layout="@layout/principal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nvView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:menu="@menu/menu"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/encabezado"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>



</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

De esta forma funciona perfectamente y al tocar alguna opción ingresa de forma correcta al fragment correspondiente.
Agradecería una solución a mi problema.

Answer (score 1):

En este caso no deberías usar un menú, deberías agregar un `ExpandableListView` el cual contendrá los elementos del menú, dentro del `DrawerLayout` .

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/frmInicio"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".vistas.Inicio">
    
    <include
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    
 <!-- <include
        layout="@layout/principal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />-->

 <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/expandable_list"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#ffff"/>
    
    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nvView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:menu="@menu/menu"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/encabezado"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>
    
    
    
    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Tu `ExpandableListView`, será llenado usando un `adapter` personalizado, ejemplo:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.jorgesys.navigationexpandablelistview.objects.ElementoMenu;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private List<String> listDataHeader;
    private HashMap<String,List<ElementoMenu>> listElementosMenu;

    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader, HashMap<String, List<ElementoMenu>> listElementosMenu) {
        this.context = context;
        this.listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this.listElementosMenu = listElementosMenu;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int i) {
        return listElementosMenu.get(listDataHeader.get(i)).size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int i) {
        return listDataHeader.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int i, int i1) {
        return listElementosMenu.get(listDataHeader.get(i)).get(i1);// i= Group item, i1 = childItem
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int i, int i1) {
        return i1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int i, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        String headerTittle = (String)getGroup(i);
        if(view == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_categoria,null);
        }
        TextView item_cate_name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_cate_name);
        item_cate_name.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        item_cate_name.setText(headerTittle);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int i, int i1, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        final String childText = listElementosMenu.get(listDataHeader.get(i)).get(i1).getTitulo();
        final int childImg =  listElementosMenu.get(listDataHeader.get(i)).get(i1).getImagenResource();
        if(view == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_subcategoria,null);
        }
        TextView item_name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_name);
        item_name.setText(childText);
        ImageView item_icon = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_scate_icon);
        item_icon.setImageResource(childImg);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int i, int i1) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Te sugiero revisar el ejemplo completo para que puedas lograr lo que deseas:

[NavigationDrawer con ExpandableListView](https://github.com/Jorgesys/NavigationDrawer-with-ExpandableListView)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]